# Make a custom method in web api and call it from angularjs

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I wan to make custom method in  Api controller and call it from angularJS $http.(get/post).
I have a view .cshtml where i use ng-repeat to get data from database given below..
[image]

Now i want to make a custom method in web api to update only 1 field (Status=1) when admin click Approve

my Api controller is :

```
using AttributeRouting;
using AttributeRouting.Web.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace HRM_Project.Controllers
{

[RoutePrefix("api/EmployeeLeaveApi")]
public class EmployeeLeaveApiController : ApiController
{
    private HRM27Entities db = new HRM27Entities();

    // GET api/EmployeeLeaveApi
    public IEnumerable<EmployeeLeave> GetEmployeeLeaves()
    {
        var employeeleaves = db.EmployeeLeaves.Include(e => e.Employee);
        return employeeleaves.AsEnumerable();
    }

    // GET api/EmployeeLeaveApi/5
    public EmployeeLeave GetEmployeeLeave(int id)
    {
        EmployeeLeave employeeleave = db.EmployeeLeaves.Find(id);
        if (employeeleave == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
        }

        return employeeleave;
    }
     PUT api/EmployeeLeaveApi/5
    public HttpResponseMessage PutEmployeeLeave(int id, EmployeeLeave employeeleave)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
        }

        if (id != employeeleave.LeaveID)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        db.Entry(employeeleave).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex);
        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
    // POST api/EmployeeLeaveApi
    public HttpResponseMessage PostEmployeeLeave(EmployeeLeave employeeleave)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.EmployeeLeaves.Add(employeeleave);
            db.SaveChanges();

            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, employeeleave);
            response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = employeeleave.LeaveID }));
            return response;
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
        }
    }

    // DELETE api/EmployeeLeaveApi/5
    public HttpResponseMessage DeleteEmployeeLeave(int id)
    {
        EmployeeLeave employeeleave = db.EmployeeLeaves.Find(id);
        if (employeeleave == null)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }

        db.EmployeeLeaves.Remove(employeeleave);

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex);
        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, employeeleave);
    }

    // [Route("Api/goals/update/{id}")]
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Api/EmployeeLeaveApi/ApproveLeave/{id}")]
    public string ApproveLeave(int id, EmployeeLeave obj)
    {
        var leaveIdFound = db.EmployeeLeaves.FirstOrDefault(x => x.LeaveID == id);

        if (leaveIdFound != null)
        {
            leaveIdFound.Status = obj.Status;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return "Customer updated successfully!";
        }

        return "Customer updated fails!";

    }
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        db.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

}

I also installed AttributeRouting package.

But when i test the using "http://localhost:30429/Api/EmployeeLeaveApi/ApproveLeave/" link i got error! Error:

> {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Multiple
>   actions were found that match the request:
>   \r\nHRM_Project.EmployeeLeave GetEmployeeLeave(Int32) on t....

I just wanna push a query like that

```
 update leaveTable set status="1" where Leaveid=12"
```

others field will be remined unchanged.

,how can do this?
Anyone one tell how can i make and use a custome web api method from angular? 
cshtml :

```
<a href="" ng-click="approveLeave(item.LeaveID)"
```

JS file:

```
$scope.approveLeave = function (a) {


        $http.put('http://localhost:30429/api/employeeleaveApi/' + a)
         .success(function (data) {
             console.log("inserted succes");

         }).error(function () {

         });
```

Comment: There is another action that effectively has the same route as this action. That's what the error means. Could you show the other actions in the API controller so we can pinpoint which one?

Comment: I edited the post with my full web api controller. I also edited js file and ng-click event as i don't need all filed send to Api.  I just need to send LeaveID and Status 2/1(2=rejected/1=approved) to the controller to update the table's status field only.

Comment: I also added before in WebApiConfig.cs as my api was not working .`code  GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore; 
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Remove(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter);`